# Process an array and group rows by one field from a csv

Tags: csv, perl

## Edit for clarity after reading several comments and answers

Consider the below CSV

```
Column1,Column2,Column3
John,Doe,Developer
Joey,Doe,Manager
Joe,Doe,Developer
```

I need to be able to read the CSV in perl to be able to render the following:

```
---- My list ----

-> Person 1
-> Name: John Doe
-> Role: Developer

-> Person 2
-> Name: Joey Doe
-> Role: Manager

-> Person 3
-> Name: Joe Doe
-> Role: Developer

--- Groups ---

-> Developer
-> Members: John Doe, Joe Doe

-> Manager
-> Members: Joey Doe

--- Roles ---
-> Developer, Manager
```

## Edit

The end environment has limitations
- Perl 5.10 and can't be upgraded
- Cannot install additional modules
- Had to use "print" instead of "say"

Comment: Could you use Perl's grep to get common lines?

Comment: Sorry, I have no knowledge of perl and things relative to, I am only familiar with php and JS. This is kind of a random side task in an attempt to improve productivity on a certain platform with several restrictions. The above is a modifed version of several code snippet I found and tried to put together.

Comment: Should the second `while` loop be reading from `$data2`, rather than `$data`? And I'm not sure why you're opening two filehandles on the same file. Have you seen [`seek()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html)?

Comment: @DaveCross yes, my mistake, should read from ```$data2```. Also opening two file handles for after running the while loop once on $data, running a second loop to group doesn't run at all since ```$data``` is then empty. I am not used to that behavior in PHP or JS so I am not sure of the right approach here. Just trying to get it to work.

Comment: *running a second loop to group doesn't run at all since `$data` is then empty* That's what I suspected you'd say. Which is why I pointed you at `seek()`.

Comment: Yeah I haven't seen the seek function. I just got confused whenever I tried to search for simple things on how to initialize an associative array or object, pushing items into, and getting errors often on the way I declare a variable. But the answer provided @Shawn seems to lead in the right direction. I just need a few adjustments and bits which am trying to sort out.

Comment: @joey: Shawn's answer is effectively the same as mine.

Comment: @DaveCross that's correct. If you can include the second loop I will mark yours as accepted answer after I fully achieve what I aimed in the question. I am still having trouble accessing items in the second loop. And I also need a sort of last "print" that gathers all these roles on one line i.e. ```print "\t",$groupKeys # expecting:  Developer, Manager```

Comment: Updated the question to clarify the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code reads data, splits on fields and build hash with keys **person**, **position**, **role**.

Once hash formed the data output to console in accordance with hash keys.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my %hash;
my %seen;
my @header = split ',', <DATA>;

chomp @header;

while(<DATA>) {
    next if /^$/;
    chomp;
    my %data;
    @data{@header} = split ',';

    push @{$hash{person}}, \%data;
    push @{$hash{Position}{$data{Position}}}, "$data{Last} $data{First}";
    if( ! $seen{$data{Position}} ) {
        $seen{$data{Position}} = 1;
        push @{$hash{Role}}, $data{Position};
    }
}

say "--- My list ----\n";

my $count = 0;
for my $person ( @{$hash{person}} ) {
    $count++;
    say "-> Person: $count";
    say "-> Name:   $person->{First} $person->{Last}";
    say "-> Role:   $person->{Position}\n";
}

say "---- Groups ----\n";

while( my($p,$m) = each %{$hash{Position}} ) {
    say "-> $p: ";
    say '-> Members: ' . join(', ',@{$m}) . "\n";
}

say "---- Roles ----";

say '-> ' . join(', ',@{$hash{Role}});

__DATA__
First,Last,Position
John,Doe,Developer
Mary,Fox,Manager
Anna,Gulaby,Developer
```

Output

```
--- My list ----

-> Person: 1
-> Name:   John Doe
-> Role:   Developer

-> Person: 2
-> Name:   Mary Fox
-> Role:   Manager

-> Person: 3
-> Name:   Anna Gulaby
-> Role:   Developer

---- Groups ----

-> Manager:
-> Members: Fox Mary

-> Developer:
-> Members: Doe John, Gulaby Anna

---- Roles ----
-> Developer, Manager
```

OP brought to my attention that he had a problem with the code.

It was found cause of the problem was input data *eol* in DOS form `\r\n` on *Linux* system. In Linux for some versions of perl [v5.22.1] - `chomp` removes only `\n` and leaves `\r` which stays part of key for *Position\r* field. Thanks goes to [Shawn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9952196/shawn) for pointing it out.

It was found that not all versions of perl experience this issue. New post was initiated to demonstrate the problem.

Following fix works for *Linux/Windows* (not tested on other platforms).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $debug = 0;

say "
Perl:  $^V
OS: $^O
-------------------
" if $debug;         # for debug purpose to show perl version and OS

my %hash;
my %seen;
my @header = split ',', <DATA>;

$header[2] = snip_eol($header[2]);    # problem fix

while(<DATA>) {
    next if /^\s*$/;

    my $line = snip_eol($_);          # problem fix

    my %data;
    @data{@header} = split ',',$line;

    push @{$hash{person}}, \%data;
    push @{$hash{Position}{$data{Position}}}, "$data{First} $data{Last}";
    if( ! $seen{$data{Position}} ) {
        $seen{$data{Position}} = 1;
        push @{$hash{Role}}, $data{Position};
    }
}

#say Dumper($hash{Position});

my $count = 0;
for my $person ( @{$hash{person}} ) {
    $count++;
    say "-> Name:   $person->{First} $person->{Last}";
    say "-> Role:   $person->{Position}\n";
}

say "---- Groups ----\n";

while( my($p,$m) = each %{$hash{Position}} ) {
    say "-> $p";
    my $members = join(',',@{$m});
    say "-> Members: $members\n";
}

say "---- Roles ----";

say '-> ' . join(', ',@{$hash{Role}});

sub snip_eol {                            # problem fix
    my $data = shift;

    #map{ say "$_ => " . ord } split '', $data if $debug;
    $data =~ s/\r// if $^O eq 'linux';
    chomp $data;
    #map{ say "$_ => " . ord } split '', $data if $debug;

    return $data;
}

__DATA__
First,Last,Position
John,Doe,Developer
Mary,Fox,Manager
Anna,Gulaby,Developer
```

Comment: Your answer works almost, only one issue. I am forced to add "," after each line otherwise I get this error ```Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at csv.pl line 31, <DATA> line 4``` when it attempts to use ```$hash{Position}```

Comment: Hmm, it sounds very strange to me. For an assurance I copied code snipped and run it once more. No error, result as posted. I tested it in Windows 10 with [Strawberry perl](http://strawberryperl.com/).

Comment: I was using Ubuntu on homestead. The final code will be running on a specific box with restrictions. In fact, the accepted answer is causing me trouble as I am unable/not allowed to install the CSV_XS module on the said environment. And I copied your answer again but still get this error ```Use of uninitialized value $config{"Column3"} in hash element at csv.pl line 21, <DATA> line 2.```

Comment: Also the perl version I am using is 5.26 but the final environment has perl 5.10, which as well, cannot be upgraded due to company security policy.

Comment: Aha, Ok now I seems understood what causes a problem in your case. If you look at **__DATA__** block of my code snippet. I renamed headers of the data -- 'First,Last,Position' (what I consider more appropriate), but in your case you have 'Column1,Column2,Column3' (which do not carry any useful information). Try to change **header** of CVS file to match 'First,Last,Position' and rerun the code once more. I am not aware where you extract these data but my code rely on header and uses it as hash keys (this is why I have changed the header to make code more _self descriptive_).

Comment: I tried your updated code, but still same issue. And when I began attempting the above task, I did observe a behavior which is same if I change your _DATA_ segment into ```__DATA__
First,Last,Position,
John,Doe,Developer,
Mary,Fox,Manager,
Anna,Gulaby,Developer,``` it would then work. But adding extra "commas" at the end of each line seems not right for a regular CSV.

Comment: Sorry but just to be clear, I ran your code as it is with the same _DATA_ and getting the mentioned error. Altering with commas at the end, resolve the issue, but I don't feel it's right to do it this way. Text::CSV_XS does seem to address the issue, but as mentioned, I am limited on the environment where I need to run this code.

Comment: Ok, I guess finally I was able to reproduce your error [run test](https://rextester.com/CHKR14537). I still do not get why this happening and what it associated with. I run same test on [other website](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_perl_online.php) and it the error does not manifest itself. What version of perl do you have installed?

Comment: @joeyj -- I did some troubleshooting and filed new [post# 60689443](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60689443/hash-content-access-is-inconsistent-with-different-perl-version) with description of my findings. It is quite interesting problem -- it does not manifest itself on my computer, but same perl version online produces an error, other perl run webpage with different version also produces the problem.

Comment: @joeyj - Ok, please see second part of answer with work around of the issue. I believe that the fix is _OS and perl version_ omnipotent.

Comment: If the environment allowed php or node, I would have been fine. Thanks a lot for helping me out, your answer works and also meets the constraints I have on the said environment.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure what you want, but this seems to produce something like your data structure.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my @headers = split (/,/, <DATA>);
chomp(@headers);

my %data;

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  my %config;
  @config{@headers} = split /,/;

  push @{$data{$config{Column3}}}, [ $config{Column1}, $config{Column2} ];
}

say Dumper \%data;

__DATA__
Column1,Column2,Column3
John,Doe,Developer
Joey,Doe,Manager
Joe,Doe,Developer
```

The output is:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Developer' => [
                           [
                             'John',
                             'Doe'
                           ],
                           [
                             'Joe',
                             'Doe'
                           ]
                         ],
          'Manager' => [
                         [
                           'Joey',
                           'Doe'
                         ]
                       ]
        };
```

And I only needed to read through the file once.

**Update:** And here's a version with all of your required output.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my @headers = split (/,/, <DATA>);
chomp(@headers);

my %data;

say "---- My list ----\n";

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  my %config;
  @config{@headers} = split /,/;

  push @{$data{$config{Column3}}}, [ $config{Column1}, $config{Column2} ];

  say "-> Person ", $. - 1;
  say "-> Name: $config{Column1}, $config{Column2}";
  say "-> Role: $config{Column3}\n";
}

say "--- Groups ---\n";

for (keys %data) {
  say "-> $_";
  say "-> Members: ", join ', ', map { "@$_" } @{$data{$_}};
  say '';
}

say "--- Roles ---\n";
say join ', ', keys %data;
say '';

__DATA__
Column1,Column2,Column3
John,Doe,Developer
Joey,Doe,Manager
Joe,Doe,Developer
```

Comment: Thanks I will try it out and let you know. To clarify, yes reading the file once would be ideal, but I still need two loop. One needs to perform a certain print, and the second a different one. The second loop wasn't in my example as I was having issues grouping correctly.

Comment: I tried the script above as it is, but got the error ```Use of uninitialized value $config{"Column3"} in hash element at csv.pl line 19, <DATA> line 2.``` sorry if I am doing something wrong, but I have 0 knowledge of Perl syntax, only the logic required to achieve what I need. Updated question to clarify what I am aiming for.

Comment: @joeyj: I was getting similar errors before I added the `chomp(@headers)` statement. Does your version include that?

Comment: I've updated my question further with a better representation of what I tried to achieve. I specifically need these two cycle, one cycling through all rows normally, and the second while they are grouped by the third column.

Comment: Sorry, edited your answer by mistake. Intended to edit the original question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why you want to read the file twice. Read it once, doing stuff for each line, and storing the groups at the same time, and then loop over them? Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say postderef/;
no warnings qw/experimental::postderef/;
use Text::CSV_XS;

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({binary => 1, auto_diag => 1});
my %roles;
# Read the header line
$csv->column_names($csv->getline(\*DATA));

say "---- My list ----";
my $n = 0;
while (my $row = $csv->getline(\*DATA)) {
    # Do stuff for the row:
    $n += 1;
    say "-> Person $n";
    say "-> name $row->[0] $row->[1]";
    say "-> Role: $row->[2]\n";
    # Group for later
    push @{$roles{$row->[2]}}, [ $row->@[0,1] ];
}

say "--- Groups ---\n";
for my $role (sort keys %roles) {
    say "-> $role";
    say "-> Members: ", join(", ", map { "@$_" } $roles{$role}->@*), "\n";
}

say "--- Roles ---";
say "-> ", join(", ", sort keys %roles);

__DATA__
Column1,Column2,Column3
John,Doe,Developer
Joey,Doe,Manager
Joe,Doe,Developer
```

(Note use of the [Text::CSV_XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS) module to parse CSV data instead of using `split`, to make it more robust, and [postderef](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2014/09/use-postfix-dereferencing/) array reference access if you haven't seen that syntax before. Personally, I think it's cleaner than the traditional de-reference syntax in some cases).

Comment: Thanks. Your answer seems to be hinting what I was looking for. I'll adapt with the csv file and update shortly as accepted answer.

Comment: I try to access ```$roles{$role}->[0]``` in the second loop but get ```ARRAY(0x56306c25fea0)``` is there something I misunderstand about variables?

Comment: @joeyj Each element of the hash is an arrayref of arrayrefs, just like the example printed out by `Data::Dumper` in the other answer. https://perldoc.pl/perllol might be a good starting point if you're not familiar with that sort of data structure.

Comment: I've updated the question to clarify the expected output. If you can update your answer to achieve the above, would really appreciate.