# SOLVED: Hash content access is inconsistent with different perl version

Tags: perl, hash

I came across an interesting problem with following piece of code in [perl 5.22.1](https://rextester.com/l/perl_online_compiler) and [perl 5.30.0](https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-perl-online/)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

#use Data::Dumper;

my %hash;
my %seen;
my @header = split ',', <DATA>;

chomp @header;

while(<DATA>) {
    next if /^\s*$/;
    chomp;
    my %data;
    @data{@header} = split ',';

    push @{$hash{person}}, \%data;
    push @{$hash{Position}{$data{Position}}}, "$data{First} $data{Last}";
    if( ! $seen{$data{Position}} ) {
        $seen{$data{Position}} = 1;
        push @{$hash{Role}}, $data{Position};
    }
}

#say Dumper($hash{Position});

my $count = 0;
for my $person ( @{$hash{person}} ) {
    say "Person: $count";
    say "Role: $person->{Position}";
}

say "---- Groups ----\n";

while( my($p,$m) = each %{$hash{Position}} ) {
    say "-> $p";
    my $members = join(',',@{$m});
    say "-> Members: $members\n";
}

say "---- Roles ----";

say '-> ' . join(', ',@{$hash{Role}});

__DATA__
First,Last,Position
John,Doe,Developer
Mary,Fox,Manager
Anna,Gulaby,Developer
```

If the code run as it is -- [everything works fine](https://rextester.com/DLP55385)

Now it is sufficient to add `$count++` increment as bellow and [code produces errors](https://rextester.com/DSW61156)

```
my $count = 0;
for my $person ( @{$hash{person}} ) {
    $count++;
    say "Person: $count";
    say "Role: $person->{Position}";
}
```

Errors:

```
Error(s), warning(s):
Use of uninitialized value $data{"Position"} in hash element at source_file.pl line 22, <DATA> line 2.
Use of uninitialized value $data{"Position"} in hash element at source_file.pl line 23, <DATA> line 2.
Use of uninitialized value $data{"Position"} in hash element at source_file.pl line 24, <DATA> line 2.
Use of uninitialized value $data{"Position"} in hash element at source_file.pl line 22, <DATA> line 3.
Use of uninitialized value $data{"Position"} in hash element at source_file.pl line 23, <DATA> line 3.
Use of uninitialized value $data{"Position"} in hash element at source_file.pl line 22, <DATA> line 4.
Use of uninitialized value $data{"Position"} in hash element at source_file.pl line 23, <DATA> line 4.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at source_file.pl line 35, <DATA> line 4.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at source_file.pl line 35, <DATA> line 4.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at source_file.pl line 35, <DATA> line 4.
Use of uninitialized value in join or string at source_file.pl line 48, <DATA> line 4.
```

This problem does not manifest itself in perl 5.30.0 (Windows 10, Strawberry Perl) or [Perl v5.24.2](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_perl_online.php).

**Note:** the problem manifests itself not only with `$count++` but with any other access to content of the hash next to `say "Person: $count";` -- [post# 60653651](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60653651/process-an-array-and-group-rows-by-one-field-from-a-csv/60662118?noredirect=1#comment107371985_60662118)

I would like to hear comments on this situation, what is the cause?

**CAUSE:** input data have *eol* in DOS form `\r\n` and when data processed in *Linux* `chomp` removes only `\n` leaving `\r` as part of the field name (used as hash key). Thanks goes to [Shawn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9952196/shawn) for pointing out the source of the issue.

**SOLUTION:** universal [fix](https://rextester.com/XBSW79657) was implemented in form of `snip_eol($arg)` subroutine

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $debug = 0;

say "
Perl:  $^V
OS: $^O
-------------------
" if $debug;

my %hash;
my %seen;
my @header = split ',', <DATA>;

$header[2] = snip_eol($header[2]);        # problem fix

while(<DATA>) {
    next if /^\s*$/;

    my $line = snip_eol($_);              # problem fix

    my %data;
    @data{@header} = split ',',$line;

    push @{$hash{person}}, \%data;
    push @{$hash{Position}{$data{Position}}}, "$data{First} $data{Last}";
    if( ! $seen{$data{Position}} ) {
        $seen{$data{Position}} = 1;
        push @{$hash{Role}}, $data{Position};
    }
}

#say Dumper($hash{Position});

my $count = 0;
for my $person ( @{$hash{person}} ) {
    $count++;
    say "-> Name:   $person->{First} $person->{Last}";
    say "-> Role:   $person->{Position}\n";
}

say "---- Groups ----\n";

while( my($p,$m) = each %{$hash{Position}} ) {
    say "-> $p";
    my $members = join(',',@{$m});
    say "-> Members: $members\n";
}

say "---- Roles ----";

say '-> ' . join(', ',@{$hash{Role}});

sub snip_eol {
    my $data = shift;                      # problem fix

    #map{ say "$_ => " . ord } split '', $data if $debug;
    $data =~ s/\r// if $^O eq 'linux';
    chomp $data;
    #map{ say "$_ => " . ord } split '', $data if $debug;

    return $data;
}

__DATA__
First,Last,Position
John,Doe,Developer
Mary,Fox,Manager
Anna,Gulaby,Developer
```

Comment: @zdim -- well it is not easy to find what is the cause of the problem. [Shawn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9952196/shawn) pointed me toward `\r` present in the data (what is not obvious as data was copy+paste - ed) -- the problem is demonstrated with following [test](https://rextester.com/ALEQN97831). The problem could be _blamed_ on `split` which in Linux snips only `\n` but not `\r\n` in this particular case. What I found strange that different versions of perl seem treat `chomp` differently.

Comment: Simpler solution: Replace `chomp;` with `s/\s+\z//r;`. But personally, I would fix the file using `dos2unix`.

Comment: @ikegami -- personally, I would fix with vim/vi `set ff=unix` and `:wq` (`dos2unix` is not available on many systems).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can replicate this behavior by (On linux) first converting the source file to have Windows-style `\r\n` line endings and then trying to run it. I thus suspect that in your testing of various versions you're using Windows sometimes, and a Linux/Unix other times, and not converting the file's line endings appropriately.

`@chomp` only removes a newline character (Well, the current value of `$/` to be pedantic), so when used on a string with a Windows style line ending in it, it leaves the carriage return. The hash key is not `"Position"`, it's `"Position\r"`, which is not what the rest of your code uses.

Comment: Ok, your assumption about `\r` was correct! I have tried [a fix](https://rextester.com/ALEQN97831) which works as expected. I find it very strange - the code was **copy+paste** into link above and of cause `\r` is not visible but as my test shows it presents there. For a few days OP was reporting the problem which just did not manifest itself on my machine -- and I was puzzled what is going on. Thank you for nudging me in right direction -- once you pointed where the problem can be it was easy to figure out the rest.

Comment: indeed, same here -- it can be checked at their link by removing `\r` after `@header` is formed.

Comment: @PolarBear: If problem is solved, than you should accept answer ;-)